# ParallelTable and Precision

Tags: parallelization, precision-and-accuracy

I'm using `ParallelTable[]` to calculate a function over a range of my parameters , ($\omega,\ell$). This seems to be working well (in terms of speed increase) except for some strange Precision issues.

I set the `$MinPrecision=40` at the start of the notebook as well as my working precision, precision goal and accuracy goal for some computations later in the notebook as

```
 wp=$MinPrecision;
 ac=$MinPrecision-8;
 pg=wp/2;
```

The rest of my code basically defines some helper functions before going on to the main function (that I feed into `ParallelTable`). This main function uses the helper functions along with `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate` to do some computations, and it's in these that I feed the `Working Precision->wp` ,`AccuracyGoal->ac`, `PrecisionGoal->pg`.

I have used `DistributeDefinitions` on all my variables, helper functions, and the main function, and even on `$MinPrecision`, also all my initial conditions for NDSolve have `N[...,wp]` wrapped around them, but still when I use `ParallelTable[...]` I get errors:

```
 Precision::precsm. Requested precision 39.153977328439204` is smaller than $MinPrecision.
```

I don't get any such error when I simply use `Do[...]` or `Table[..]` on my main function, and indeed the results differ at the 33rd decimal place, which is the decimal the above number is precision too. I have no idea what this number is unfortunately, it doesn't look like any of my outputs or inputs.

I just don't understand how this could not crop up with the non-parallelized forms, but crop up with parallelized?

**Minimal Example**

This is much simpler than my code, but I think it still captures it and the problem:

Definitions:

```
M = 1;
$MinPrecision = 40;
    wp = $MinPrecision;
ac = $MinPrecision - 8;
pg = wp/2;
rinf = 15000;
```

The main function to be parallelized:

```
dGenBessE[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, l_?IntegerQ] := 
Block[{\[CapitalPhi]out, init, dinit},

init = 0.00006630728036817007679447778124486601253323 + 
6.913102762021489976135937610105907096265*10^-6 I;
dinit = -6.958226432502243329110910813935678705519*10^-7 + 
6.631148430876236565520382557577187147081*10^-6 I;

  \[CapitalPhi]out[\[Omega], l] = \[CapitalPhi] /. 
  Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100}, 
      NDSolve[{\[CapitalPhi]''[r] + (2 (r - M))/(
           r (r - 2 M)) \[CapitalPhi]'[
            r] + ((\[Omega]^2 r^2)/(r - 2 M)^2 - (l (l + 1))/(
             r (r - 2 M))) \[CapitalPhi][r] == 
         0, \[CapitalPhi][rinf] == 
         N[init, wp], \[CapitalPhi]'[rinf] == 
         N[dinit, wp]}, \[CapitalPhi], {r, 30, 40}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> wp, AccuracyGoal -> ac, 
       PrecisionGoal -> pg, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]][[1]];
     Print["For \[Omega]=", \[Omega], " and l=", l, ": "];
     Print["Kernel ID: ", $KernelID];
 Print["Precision of init: ", Precision[init]];
 Print["Precision of dinit: ", Precision[dinit]];
 Print["\[CapitalPhi]out at 35=" , 
N[\[CapitalPhi]out[\[Omega], l][35], wp] ];
 Print["Precision of \[CapitalPhi]out: ", 
 Precision[\[CapitalPhi]out[\[Omega], l][35]]];
]
```

Do Paralleization prereqs:

```
LaunchKernels[4]
DistributeDefinitions[M, rinf, wp, ac, pg, $MinPrecision,dGenBessE];
```

Attempt to run it with Paralleize for two different values:

```
Parallelize[{dGenBessE[1/10, 0], dGenBessE[1/10, 1]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

**Result**

For me this leads to a

```
Precision::precsm: Requested precision 38.95475956978393` is smaller than   $MinPrecision. Using $MinPrecision instead.
```

Comment: Can you give a small example? I cannot reproduce your behavior.

Comment: OK, will try and strip down my code to essentials that reproduce then repost soon.

Comment: you can run `ParallelEvaluate[<your variable>]` to see if they were distributed OK.

Comment: @halirutan now put a minimal example which reproduces behaviour. @Ajasja, thanks that's a useful feature. All my variables seem OK across the four Kernels, although if I run `ParallelEvaluate[$MinPrecision]` I get `{0,0,0,0}` but that isn't really a variable so...If I run `ParallelEvaluate[dGenBess]` then I get `{dGenBess,dGenBess,dGenBess,dGenBess}` rather than function definitions, not sure if that is expected or not.

Comment: @fpghost `ParallelEvaluate[Definition@dGenBess]` is more useful (watch the spelling, sometimes you have dGenBess and sometimes dGenBessE)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem arises because the value of `$MinPrecision` is not distributed correctly (If I remember correctly none of the variables in the `System` context are distributed automatically).

So we have to do this by hand

```
ParallelEvaluate[$MinPrecision = 40]

Parallelize[{dGenBessE[1/10, 0], dGenBessE[1/10, 1]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Should now work without problems.

Also, presonally I would write the last example as

```
ParallelMap[dGenBessE[1/10, #]&,{0,1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

or

```
Parallelize@Scan[dGenBessE[1/10, #] &, {0, 1}]
```

depending on whether you need to return values or not.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick, thanks. I'll keep `System` variables distribution in mind in future.

Comment: I don't suppose you know a clever way to get the `AbsoluteTiming` of each element of `ParallelTable`?

Comment: @fpghost What about `ParallelMap[AbsoluteTiming[dGenBessE[1/10, #]] &, {0, 1}]`?

Comment: Strange that works when I replace my `dGenBessE` by a simple function like `g[x_]:=x^2` then do `ParallelMap[AbsoluteTiming[g[#]] &, {0, 1}]` say, but not for my actual function. When in the same notebook `ParallelTable[dGenBess[...]` is executing fine. I should note that my Table will be iterating over two vairables and that `1/10` fixed in the above, will be looped over too. So I don't know if Map will be good to get the timing at each point in the 2d grid? Although this isn't the problem with your timing method as I copied what you put verbatim keeping the `1/10` fixed..

Comment: This appears to have actually worked. Congratulations.