# ParallelTable local variables don't update precision

Tags: parallelization, precision-and-accuracy

I'm finding that precision of variables updated outside ParallelTable don't update inside of it the way I'd hope. Here's the minimal code that demonstrates my point:

```
a1 = SetPrecision[1.0, 20];
Precision[a1]
ParallelTable[
  Print[Precision[a1]];
  , {j, 1}];
a1 = SetPrecision[1.0, 30];
a2 = a1;
Precision /@ {a1, a2}
ParallelTable[
  Print[Precision /@ {a1, a2}];
  , {j, 1}];
```

which outputs

```
20.
20.
{30., 30.}
{20.,30.}
```

The key problem is that output lines 3 and 4 aren't the same. a1 is defined differently inside and outside ParallelTable. Why is this and how can I make sure a1 is properly updated?

For contrast, note the problem does not occur if a1 has its value updated instead of its precision:

```
a1 = 1.0;
a1
ParallelTable[
  Print[a1];
  , {j, 1}];
a1 = 2.0;
a2 = a1;
{a1, a2}
ParallelTable[
  Print[{a1, a2}];
  , {j, 1}];
```

output:

```
1.
1.
{2., 2.}
{2.,2.}
```

Some possibly related questions:

[ParallelTable and Precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13677/paralleltable-and-precision)

-- This seems to answer a related but different question?

[ParallelTable and Table do not give same result](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/paralleltable-and-table-do-not-give-same-result)

-- I couldn't quite grasp this one to figure out if it was answering my question. A more straightforward answer would be very helpful.

Comment: Insert `SetSharedVariable[a1, a2];` after the assignment `a2=a1`. This will fix it. Not completely sure what's going on though...

Comment: What you are doing updates the precision on the master kernel, but not on the slave kernels. Alternatively to what @Lukas said (if you don't want to make the variables shared variables) you can also use `ParallelEvaluate` to update the precision.

Comment: @sebhofer Also thought so... But why is then the precision for `a2` correct on the slave? That disturbed me

Comment: @Lukas Without having checked the details, there is one obvious difference between `a1` and `a2`: `a1` already exists in the context of the slave kernels, while `a2` does not. `ParallelTable` automatically distributes the definition of `a2`, but apparently does not update `a1` (which seems to be reasonable behaviour to me). Again, I didn't check this in detail, just a guess.

Comment: @sebhofer Right, that makes sense. I overlooked that only `a1` existed before the first `ParallelTable`. I guess you're right

Comment: @sebhofer What makes you say this is reasonable behavior? If you do something similar where a1 changes its value (say to 2.0) instead of its precision the slave kernels get the update immediately. So why should an update not happen when the precision is changed but not the value? I'll add code for this to my question.

Comment: Max, I agree this seems like strange behavior. I can't tell you why this is implemented the way it is, but see my answer for a partial explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing can be traced back to the behavior of `DistributeDefinitions` which is used internally by `ParallelTable`. `DistributeDefinitions` seems to have some way to determine which of its argument should *in fact* be distributed [1]. If the value of a variable is unchanged, it will do nothing. Consider the following snippet, for example:

```
a1 = SetPrecision[1.0, 20];
DistributeDefinitions[a1]
(*{a1}*)
DistributeDefinitions[a1]
(*{}*)
```

The empty braces indicate that nothing was distributed. Now, a change of precision will not trigger such an update, as can be seen when evaluating

```
a1 = SetPrecision[2.0, 20];
DistributeDefinitions[a1]
(*{a1}*)
a1 = SetPrecision[2.0, 30];
DistributeDefinitions[a1]
(*{}*)
```

I can't tell you why this is the case, maybe someone else can shed light on this. As to how to work around this, we already mentioned several possible ways in the comments:

- Using shared variables (note that this of course has additional side-effects you may or may not want)

  ```
  SetSharedVariable[a1]
  a1 = SetPrecision[2.0, 20]
  ```
- Manually setting the precision on all kernels

  ```
  ParallelEvaluate[a1 = SetPrecision[2.0, 20]]
  ```

[1] As an aside I want to mention that the documentation seems incorrect, or confusing at the least. It states: "`DistributeDefinitions` in effect applies `ParallelEvaluate` to all assignments for values and attributes with the symbols [...], including not only ownvalues but also downvalues, upvalues, and other types of values."